# Roots of complex polynomial in $S^1$

Tags: complex-analysis

roots of complex polynomial
Let is $ p(z) = a_0 + ... + a_n z^n$ such that $a_n$ is not equal to zero there is $ j \in \{0, ... ,n \}$ with $ |a_j| > ( \sum_{k=0}^n |a_k|) - |a_j| $. Show that the polynomial  $g(z) = p(z) - a_jz^j$ has not roots  in $S^1 = \{ z; |z| = 1\}$.

Comment: Sorry in problem about , we have that $ |a_j| > \( \sum_{k=0}^n |a_k|\) - |a_k| $

Comment: Did you perchance mean to write $\vert a_j \vert \le (\sum_{k = 0}^n \vert a_k \vert) - \vert a_j \vert$?

Comment: No, sorry. In problem we have that $ |a_j| > \( \sum_{k=0}^n |a_k|\) - |a_k| $. Sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: My real question concerns the presence of $\vert a_k \vert$ subtracted from the sum on the right; are you sure you don't want $\vert a_j \vert$ there?

Comment: Now the problem  is correct.

Comment: Yes, now it makes sense.  One further question:  did you want to show there are no zeroes *on* $S^1 = \{ \vert z \vert= 1 \}$, or *within* $S^1$, i.e. in $\{ \vert z \vert \le 1 \}$?  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis I think it's *on* and not *within*. If $p(z)$ satisfies the stated conditions then so does $z\cdot p(z)$, so $z\cdot g(z)$ has $z = 0$ as a root.

Comment: Darth Geek, can you show that $g(z)$ has not roots in $S^1$ ?

Comment: I think your looking for how many roots of the given polynomial is within the unit sphere, no?

Answer (score 2):

**Counterexample:**

Let $p(z) = z^2 + 3z -1$. Then $|a_0| = 1, |a_1| = 3, |a_2| = 1$.

Clearly $3 = |a_1| > |a_0| + |a_2| = 2$, so $g(z) = z^2 - 1$.

But the roots of $g(z)$ are $\pm 1\in S^1$.